# Jquery div display error

Tags: jquery

Please check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJq8b/)

Should it not be working? Am I doing something wrong?

```
<a href="#" id="#dwkere">link</a>
<div id="form-holder">text</div>
```

```css
#form-holder {
    display: none;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 991;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dwkere").click(function(){
        $("#form-holder").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=40)");
    });
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I can see a pretty long list of problems TBH.

Comment: `id="#dwkere"` isn't valid. Change it to id="dwkere".

Comment: Rory I want to make a div appear after clicking a link

Answer (score 4):

There were bunch of problems,

1. Removed `#` inside the link tag id
2. Missing `});` for document ready
3. jQuery not included in jsfiddle
4. Changed to `.css('opacity', 0.4)` as jQuery handles it across browser
5. Modified CSS for the div as it was absolute positioned and shown just above the link tag making it impossible to click.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rJq8b/8/

Use below demo in case if you want the element to be hidden before the opacity was applied.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rJq8b/18/ [as mentioned by [Travis J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199669/jquery-div-display-error/13199772#comment17970352_13199772)]

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="dwkere">link</a>
<div id="form-holder">text</div>
```

**CSS:**

`#form-holder {background:#fff;opacity:0.9;position:fixed;top:20;left:20;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:991;}`

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dwkere").click(function() {       
        $("#form-holder").css('opacity', 0.4);
    });
});
```

Comment: One suggestion that I would make. I am not sure that the OP wanted the text visible before the click (or really sure of what the intent was haha), perhaps leave the `display:none` in and then inside of your click handler add `$("#form-holder").css('display', 'block');`

Comment: +1 simply for having the patience to dissect this trainwreck

Comment: done.. i will upload the right code in a minute

Comment: Here is the answer to the problem:

    <a href="#" id="dwkere">link</a>
    <div id="form-holder">text</div>

    #form-holder {display:none;background:#000;opacity:0.9;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;min-width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:991;}

    $("#dwkere").click(function(){
    $("#form-holder").css("display", "block");});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rJq8b/19/ the jsfiddle